# Optimizing an sql query for efficiency

Tags: mysql, database-performance, query-performance

I have a query dealing with geo distances. The query is super fast, returning in roughly .1175 seconds on my 2.24 million row table. However, I only need the lowest distance, and using the built-in order by is way too slow.

Is there any way to just keep track of a running minimum and just give me that?

For example, if I have these results:

```
city a - 45km
city b - 48km
city c - 12km
```

can I just have it give me the 12km, keeping in mind that all the distance values are calculated?

Here is the query that sorts:

```
SELECT 
City, 
( 
    6371 * 
    acos(
        cos(radians(-60.61384878636903)) * 
        cos(radians(st_x(location))) * 
        cos(radians(st_y(location)) - 
        radians(112.80061386895574)) + 
        sin(radians(-60.61384878636903)) * 
        sin(radians(st_x(location))))
    ) as distance 
FROM table_name 
HAVING distance <  5 
ORDER BY distance ASC LIMIT 1
```

The table structure is as follows:

```
id - int(12)
location - Point()
City - varchar(255)
```

The problem lies in that the order by flag takes way too long to sort the data and get the lowest. Can it just keep a running minimum and then just give me that without a major performance hit?

the table contain,

```
2227851 - rows
spatial index on location
```

the run times i am getting are around 14 seconds if i use order by if i don't use order by i am getting times of .1 seconds which is my desired run time or close to it

Comment: Have you thought about doing some algebra on the equation to simplify it? At least just put a constant value for ` cos(radians(-60.61384878636903))` for example

Comment: Just for fun, did you try `WHERE 6371 * acos...`. Also you can filter the data set by excluding values outside a bounding rectangle (well, a square) of radius 5.

Comment: Performance questions should include `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. `Slow` is a relative term and we need a real value to compare.

[**MySQL**](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15371/how-do-i-get-the-execution-plan-for-a-view)

Comment: To returns result from this query, database needs to calculate all the rows and then find all records with distance less than 5 and then get the lowest value. have you tried using MIN, instead of sorting? OR is there any logic that you can find the minimum distance using only "location" field?

Comment: in response to Ed Heal the number in there is a lat/long in degrees input from a user so in this case i used a place holder.

Comment: FLICKER, i tried using min and its run times are the same around 12- 15 seconds, other than just having the lowest value there really isn't a way to guess the lowest value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's not really a way to keep a running minimum, at the query level.

The basic problem is that the minimum distance is going to be different for different values of latitude and longitude, the search coordinates being supplied as literals in the query.

One option is to keep a table of previous search coordinates, ones you've looked up before, and then use that to short circuit the need to do another query. First do a search of the table of previous searches, and get the result from there.

Of course, if you add a row to `table_name`, you'd probably need to re-evaluate the saved search coordinates against the new row, and determine if the new row is a shorter distance than what you have saved. (Or just invalidate the entire store, and repopulate for each search you do.)

---

The basic problem is that the "great-circle distance" expression has to be evaluated for every row in `table_name`.

The result of that expression is going to differ for different search values 
(latitude and longitude).

There's no getting around doing that calculation for every row, and out of all those results, finding the lowest value. That's gonna be a "Using filesort" operation. With the LIMIT 1, we'd hope that MySQL doesn't have to sort the entire set, and that it can just take one pass to identify the smallest value.

If you can limit the number of rows from `table_name` that need to be evaluated, and you can exclude them efficiently using an index... that would speed up the query.

One way to limit the number of rows would be to define a "bounding box", based on the search latitude and longitude. And specify that in the WHERE clause. And have MySQL use an appropriate index. The roughest bounding box could be defined as +/-dx degrees of latitude and +/-dy  degrees of longitude from the search coordinates... e.g.

```
 WHERE  t.lat BETWEEN  -60.613848 -4 AND -60.613848 +4 
   AND  t.lon BETWEEN  120.800613 -8 AND 120.800613 +8
```

That's not an ideal bounding box, because degrees of longitude are much longer distance at the equator than they are near the poles.

---

As far as keeping "running minimum"... can't be done with your current query. And it can't be done without some other data store that is somehow keyed to the search parameters.

Comment: the table is fixed size it contains all the city's that it will ever contain short of new cities being made.

Comment: If you were looking for the closest city in a particular state, or region, or country, or whatever, you could use that in a predicate in the WHERE clause (along with an appropriate index) to filter out rows that can be excluded. But (obviously) that may not be an appropriate fit your use case, and it would entail adding and populating columns to `the_table`. And finding the minimum distance "as the crow flies" doesn't necessarily find the "closest" in terms of travel time or distance.

Answer (score 3):

Recomendations:

- Better performance came with use MySql **[spatial functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/spatial-analysis-functions.html)** and Index

But if you dont want use it

- Precalculate constants `Set A = cos(radians(-60.61384878636903))` cos function are very slow.
- Filter your sample data. If your point of origin is `X,Y`  you can create a square  `X +- 5, Y +- 5` and use regular index on `X,Y`

Comment: so for the square its really hard to tell if the square will contain the answer, and the real hit to performance is getting the smallest distance which is the value that i am after any hints on that?

Comment: why is hard? If you have a point at `(0,0)` anything more left  than `(-5,0)` will be `> 5 distance ` so you are filtering data wont match your condition. Of course you need to convert `5` to decimal degree so you can do `X +- DeltaX`